# Facebook Login - consent dialog social login [Ionic native facebook]

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to use Facebook third-party login with ionic. Every time I am trying to initiate a log in from the app and when I want it to open up the Facebook app for login it first displays a dialog asking for user consent:

`[App] wants to log in with “Facebook” This allows the app and website to share information about you`

Once I clicked continue and again after I try same it show again with same message. I don't know why once I assign permission to continue then why it will display every time when I try login with Facebook. I need to display it only one time at user was try Facebook login first time once user click continue then it will not shown again and again.
[image]

Comment: Is it even possible to do this? Even in swift this question appears

Comment: @AndréVicente may be changes for IOS 11.x and grater to allow user to share data between safari and app, Facebook added this changes in latest sdk.